# Why does fmincon yield different solutions

Tags: matlab

I am very new to MatLab. Thus I am sorry if this is very basic.

I use a function called fmincon to do find a solution for minimizing a function. Why do I get different solutions for running fmincon?

I would like to know a satisfying or convincing mathematical or programming explanation for having different solutions using fmincon.

Comment: Did you use different initial point in each time?

Comment: My initial point is based on a random number generator vector whose summation of elements should be unity (1). Thus, it generate different number in each run, but the unity condition remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [these limitations](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busp5fq-7) in the MATLAB documentation.

fmincon is a gradient-based method that is designed to work on problems where the objective and constraint functions are both continuous and have continuous first derivatives.

The function is very delicate and it is best if you can avoid it. It only works neatly on problems that are neatly defined to begin with. Any deviation can lead to local instead of global minima, and these can depend (among other things) on your initial solution estimate or starting point.

Answer (score 0):

As `fmincon` is sensitive to initial point, If you set different start point for the `fmincon`, you might get a different solution in each apply. You can find one of the algorithms of `fmincon` [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-scalar-objective-functions.html#bu2xbye-1).